# Firefox won't work in headless mode

Tags: firefox, screenshot

When I try to use FF headless to take a screenshot of a website by:

```
firefox -screenshot google.com
```

FF refuses to run with the following error message:

```
*** You are running in headless mode.
Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart your system.
```

I am running FF 58.0.2.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Re: "Firefox is already running", do you indeed have another running instance of Firefox?

Comment: Do you already have running instances of `firefox`?

Comment: Yes, I do. I use FF in a normal mode to browse the web. Is this a problem? I thought the browser in headless mode was supposed to work alongside 'normal' instances running.

Comment: Well, it appears to be having trouble communicating with itself.  Try terminating all currently-running copies of Firefox, and running the command again.  Presuming that it works, go ahead and start an interactive session again, and try your command yet once more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error message tries to say (I get the more explanatory "A copy of Firefox is already open. Only one copy of Firefox can be open at a time."), you cannot have more than one Firefox running at a time using the same profile. One simple solution would be to create a separate profile for screenshots (run once with `firefox -P` to create such a profile, I named mine "screenshots", for example), and then explicitly use the new profile when attempting to create screenshots:

```
firefox -screenshot google.com -P screenshots
```

You may additionally need `-no-remote`, as reported by Stack of Pancakes in a comment.

Comment: This worked for me only after adding `-no-remote` to the end of the command.

Comment: Thanks, @StackofPancakes. I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: I am trying but it just hangs... No screenshot are generated in the directory.